# Matching "Casa" String with oSeries.name doesn't match in VBA

Tags: string, excel, comparison, vba

This VBA code try to paint the "Casa" line in black colour:

```
Dim ActiveSheet As Worksheet
Dim oChart As Chart
Dim oSeries As Series

Set ActiveSheet = Sheets("Gráficas")
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Gráfico 200").Activate
Set oChart = ActiveChart

For numLine = 1 To oChart.SeriesCollection.Count
    Set oSeries = oChart.SeriesCollection(numLine)
    MsgBox oSeries.name
    If oSeries.name = "Casa" Then
        MsgBox "Success"
        oSeries.Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    End If
Next
```

But what happens is that I see the names of all lines in chart, including "Casa" but no Success message painted, nor line black painted.
It seems that the String doesn't match... but why?

Comment: I guess the name can't be "Casa" exactly?

Comment: The Chart have three lines, whose name I see in the MsgBoxes. One of them is "Casa". I wonder why the code don't go inside the If condition.

Comment: Perhaps there is a trailing space. Try stepping through your code. Clearly it is not exactly "Casa" otherwise you would be seeing the message box.

Comment: Yes, there was an Extra character (CRLF) at the end of String...  :-( 
 oSeries.Name

        : Name : "Casa
" : String
I managed to Trim the String and now it works... 
Sorry !